# Condition handlers in R

Tags: r

I have been reading Hadley Wickham's Advanced R for a couple of weeks and I have reached the conditions section. In one of the exercises I came across this question and I could not figure out the explanation. I would be grateful if you could explain it to me a little bit:

Q. Explain the results of running this code:

```
withCallingHandlers(
 message = function(cnd) message("b"),
 withCallingHandlers(
  message = function(cnd) message("a"),
  message("c")
)
)
#> b
#> a
#> b
#> c
```

I just don't understand what are default and parent handlers and why running `message(c)` first triggers the `message(b)` than `message(a)`. An explanation is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, c bubbles up  to a and b, since a is closer, a bubbles up to b. So b prints, then a prints. Then since c had bubbled up to b, b prints, and finally c prints.

In other words, c triggers a and then a triggers b.  The message shows up last after triggering everything that there is to be triggered.

Here is another example to drive it home. c bubbles to d, a, and b with d being closest and b being farthest. d bubbles to a and b. a bubbles to b. So b is first. Then a. Then b. Then d. Then c had bubbled to a. And a bubbles to b, so b is printed. Then a. Finally, c had bubbled to b, so b is printed. Lastly, c is printed.

```
withCallingHandlers(
  message = function(cnd) message("b"),
  withCallingHandlers(
    message = function(cnd) message("a"),
    withCallingHandlers(
      message=function(m) {print("hi");message("d")},
      message("c")
    )
  )
)

[1] "hi"
b
a
b
d
b
a
b
c
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much dear Stacker, I really appreciate you took time out to answer my question and also drew sketch for me they were very helpful and informative. I think I understand it now clearly.